# Can an encrypted MySQL restart without the keyring file on the box?

Tags: mysql, encryption

I am running Mysql 5.7 with a few tables in the DB encrypted, if I move the keyring file off of the box to secure it, can I still restart the DB without issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, mysql will start, but you will receive an error if you try to access the encrypted table.